# Google Spreadsheet getValue([cell containing \t]) does not return a tabulator

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a cell in a google spreadsheet containing the text "s/ *│ */\t/g".

I am using the code

```
function minimalExample(){
  var text = "a │ b"

  var pattern = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B3').getValue() // cell contains "s/ *│ */\t/g"
  var regexSplitter = /s\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(\w+)/;      // pattern to split sed line into search/replace/modifier
  var patternParts = pattern.match(regexSplitter);   // list with search [1], replace [2], modifier [3]

  text = text.replace(new RegExp(patternParts[1], patternParts[3]),patternParts[2]);
  Logger.log(text);

  return true;
}
```

The intended output would be "a   b" but I get "a\tb".

How can I change this behaviour?

Comment: Why would the intended output be `a    b`? You are getting `a\tb` because *that's exactly what's written in the cell*. The things which makes a tab out of a `"\t"` you put in your code is basically the parser which reads your code. Strings loaded from elsewhere won't magically transform. If you want to convert all `\t`s in your string to tab characters, you would need to do `.replace(/\\t/g, "\t")` on it.

Comment: Then, "a  b" would be the _desired_ output :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me your code works fine:

```
[16-05-18 18:20:27:447 CEST] \t   is not the same as
```

However I guess your real code looks different and does a comparison like `patternParts[2] == "\t"`, because the characters `\t` are indeed different than the invisible tabulator after `is not the same as`.

So, the thing is the other way round: `patternParts[2]` does indeed contain `\t` but you are comparing it incorrectly. In JavaScript, you can use escape sequences such as `\n`, `\t`, `\uXXXX` etc. when using doublequotes.

So if you want to compare `patternParts[2]` with `\t`, either use single quotes (`patternParts[2] == '\t'`) or escape the backslash (`patternParts[2] == "\\t"`).

**EDIT:** According to your updated question: If you want to actually convert all `\t`s in the cell (which is just those two characters, `\` and `t`, nothing special) to tabs, then you would need to go and replace them:

```
patternParts[2] = patternParts[2].replace(/\\t/g, "\t");
```

If you have JavaScript-compatible escape sequences in your replace part, you could also use a trick such as `JSON.parse('"' + theString + '"')` to make JS replace all the escape sequences in there. Note that this will throw an exception if invalid stuff such as stray unescaped doublequotes are in your string, so watch out for that:

```
try {
    patternParts[2] = JSON.parse('"' + patternParts[2] + '"');
} catch(e) {
    // Invalid syntax! Handle the error here somehow
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I expressed myself wrong and the example was too minimal. I edited the code and added the intended vs. the actual output.